# Get all URLs on an HTML webpage

Tags: code-golf, parsing, internet

This is a rewrite of the (currently closed) ["Debunking Stroustrup's debunking of the myth “C++ is for large, complicated, programs only”"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44278/debunking-stroustrups-debunking-of-the-myth-c-is-for-large-complicated-pro) challenge.

### Challenge

Write the **shortest** program or function that will:

1. Download [`http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html`](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html), and
2. List all URLs contained in the HTML document.

A "URL" for this challenge is

- some string of characters
- contained in the `href` attribute of an `<a>` tag
- that starts with `http://` or `https://`.

So `<a href="someotherpage.html">` doesn't have a URL, but `<a href="http://someotherpage.html">` does.

### Additional Rules

- You may assume the downloaded HTML is valid.
- You may not assume the input is static: you must download the page each time your code is run.
- (as a consequence of above) You may not hardcode the output URLs: this is not [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity), this is [parsing](/questions/tagged/parsing).
- You may use either `http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html` or `https://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html` as your source URL.

### Validation

The first 5 URLs on the page (based on a [snapshot of the site on April 3, 2023](https://web.archive.org/web/20230403161526id_/https://stroustrup.com/C++.html)) are:

```
https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md
http://webhostinggeeks.com/science/programming-language-be
https://coderseye.com/stroustrup-the-c-programming-language
http://edutranslator.com/jazyk-programmirovanija-c/
https://pngset.com/uz-cplusplus
```

There are 91 URLs in this particular snapshot.

Comment: Related:
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119949/download-a-file-from-the-internet
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44481/code-golf-image-downloader

Comment: beware Tony the Pony...

Comment: This challenge seems unclear. Can we assume that the page will stay unchanged? Do we have to actually parse the HTML, or is it enough to look for a pattern like `f="http`, which could produce false positives?

Comment: @xigoi You may not assume that the page will stay the same between runs of your program. It is up to you how you get the URLs; regardless of method, you should get 91 URLs when you run your program against the snapshot linked under "Validation".

Comment: "You may assume the downloaded HTML is valid." even though it [very much isn't](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.stroustrup.com%2FC%2B%2B.html).

Answer (score 7):

## [Windows PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>70</s> <s>63</s> 61 bytes

Try it in a PowerShell Console (works in PowerShell Core 7.3 on Windows as well, but  not in TIO)

```powershell
(iwr www.stroustrup.com/C++.html|% L*).href-match'^https?://'
```

Ungolfed:

```powershell
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html' | ForEach-Object -MemberName Links).href -match '^https?://'
```

Nothing remarkable (except that PS is somewhat competitive here) going on; `iwr` is  an alias for Invoke-WebRequest, the object returned is passed to `%` (an Alias for `ForEach-Object`) which will call the object's member `Links` (the only one matching `L*`). `href` contains the parsed URL, and the `-match` weeds out local links as requested.

**Edit**: Removed the `http://` (-7 bytes), fixed the regex, replaced Link property with ForEach-Object; thanks to @Julian

**Edit**: -2 bytes thanks to thanks to @spookycoder: removed the quotes around the uri (d'oh).

Comment: The `http://www.` can be omitted and `Links` can be shortened to `|% L*`: `(iwr 'stroustrup.com/C++.html'|% L*).href-match'^https?://'`, I also changed the regex to '^https?://' so that http links would be taken in account too?

Comment: @Julian thanks for noticing; I swear I had the `?` in the regex when I was counting the results with `| measure`. The `www` can't be omitted, as the response will then be coming from `https://stroustrup.com/C++.html`, and the rules explicitly include the www.

Comment: you may ommit the single quotes around the link for saving additional 2 bytes

Answer (score 5):

## [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup), <strike>72</strike>, <strike>70</strike>, 63 bytes

```
curl -sL stroustrup.com/C++.html |
pup 'a[href^=http] attr{href}'
```

Comment: I think changing the second line to `pup 'a[href^=http] attr{href}'` and getting rid of the `grep` line is a couple of bytes shorter (not tested)

Comment: @Jacob: right you are, thanks

Comment: You’ll want to get rid of `grep` from the title as well.

Comment: `http://` is not needed with `-L`. Anyway nice job on the cleanest looking solution.

Comment: You might be able to get rid of the newline too.

Comment: @qwr: thanks. They byte-count is without redundant whitespace

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor 0.98](https://factorcode.org/) + `html.parser.analyzer http.client`, <s>143</s> <s>132</s> <s>128</s> <s>124</s> 93 bytes

```factor
[ "stroustrup.com/C++.html"http-get parse-html find-hrefs
[ protocol>> "http"head? ] filter ]
```

[image]

A function that returns a list of URLs.

- `"stroustrup.com/C++.html"http-get` push the http response and the raw html (as a string) of the url on the data stack
- `parse-html` parse the html into a sequence of [tag](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-tag%2Chtml.parser.html) tuples
- `find-hrefs` get all hrefs on the page as URLs
- `[ protocol>> "http"head? ] filter` select the URLs whose protocols start with `http`

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <strike>50</strike> <strike>48</strike> 40 bytes

```bash
curl -L stroustrup.com/C++.html|grep tp
```

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <strike>64</strike> 56 bytes

(-8 thanks to Tihit)

With tags removed

```bash
curl -L stroustrup.com/C++.html|grep -oP '"\Khttp[^"]*'
```

Comment: You can replace `https://www.` with `-L`

Comment: Why wouldn't that match "`the tplink router is a good one`"?

Comment: I can't find the string you are referring to anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

## Python3 + [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/), 109 bytes:

```python
import requests as r,re
re.findall('a href="(https*[^"]+)',r.get('https://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html').text)
```

Comment: I think you actually have to use the URL in the question rather than create a function which accepts any URL

Comment: Probably add a `print` as well

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>193 … 121</s> 117 bytes

Big port of [my hyperscript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260514/108687), parsing HTML by chucking it into the `<body>`.

This program [must be run from the site's root](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13626/58974) to avoid CORS issues. You can test it by pasting it into the browser console at [this page](https://stroustrup.com/index.html). There is a snippet below that uses a CORS proxy to do the same without running on a different domain.

```javascript
async _=>((d=document.body).innerHTML=await(await fetch`C++.html`).text(),[...d.querySelectorAll`[href*=":`].join`
`)
```

```js
f=
async _=>((d=document.body).innerHTML=await(await fetch`//corsproxy.io/?https://stroustrup.com/C++.html`).text(),[...d.querySelectorAll`[href*=":`].join`
`)

f().then(s => document.write(`<pre>${s}</pre>`))
```

```javascript
async _ => (                            // asynchronous function
  (d=document.body)                       // alias the <body> to d
    .innerHTML =                           // put into its html:
      await (await fetch`...`).text(),    //   fetch the document
  [...d.querySelectorAll`[href*=":`]      // get all tags with href containing a “:”
    .join`\n`                             // join by newlines  (<a> stringified is its href)
)
```

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>236 … 134</s> 130 bytes

This parses HTML using the `DOMParser#parseFromString` method. Ditto for the CORS stuff.

```javascript
async _=>[...new DOMParser().parseFromString(await(await fetch`C++.html`).text(),"text/html").querySelectorAll`[href*=":`].join`
`
```

```js
f=
async _=>[...new DOMParser().parseFromString(await(await fetch`//corsproxy.io/?https://stroustrup.com/C++.html`).text(),"text/html").querySelectorAll`[href*=":`].join`
`

f().then(s => document.write(`<pre>${s}</pre>`))
```

```javascript
async _ =>                                // asynchronous function
  [...                                    // cast to an array:
    new DOMParser().parseFromString(      //   parse HTML from
      await (await fetch`...`).text(),    //     fetch the document
      "text/html"
    ).querySelectorAll`[href*=":`         // get all tags with href containing a “:”
  ].join`\n`                              // join by newlines (<a> stringified is its href)
```

---

Saved 7 bytes on each version thanks to a cool trick pointed out by @tsh

Saved 39 bytes by running the program from the site's root, as pointed out by @Shaggy.

Comment: Is it correct? It returns (for me) many more urls than 91.

Comment: @pajonk Fixed and saved a bunch of bytes :)

Comment: Maybe `.map(a=>a.href)` can be `.join\`\n\``?

Comment: `.join` will automatically toString each item, which will yield their URLs.

Comment: @tsh Huh, I didn’t know that `<a>.toString` yields its href. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You can [require that this be run from the root domain of the site](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13626/58974).

Comment: Ah, forgot about that @Shaggy. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 53 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žZ.•‹Ìe¨¹w•’.ŒŒ/C++.ŠÎ’J.w'"¡ü2ʒ`žXžY‚Å?às…aØ·=Å¿*}€θ
```

`.w` is disabled on TIO, so here are two loose TIO's to verify it's working as intended:

1. `žZ.•‹Ìe¨¹w•’.ŒŒ/C++.ŠÎ’J` - Verify the url is correct: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4ovUcNix417Dzck3poxaGd5WDeTL2jk45O0nfW1tY7uuBwH1DA6/9/AA).
2. `` '"¡ü2ʒ`žXžY‚Å?às…aØ·=Å¿*}€θ `` - Verify the extraction of the URLs from the HTML content and final output is correct: [try it online](https://tio.run/##7VxJcxtJdj4PfkUaE6PFjSoQ4M4WqQCpjWpxaZKiWnORE1UJoMRCVamyiiBkT8TERMwf8Mnh8MH2wae52wfHOGI65uKDf0T/kfb3XmYtWChKHeO5eCamxQIqM@vly7d8bynEWvYD9eOP95t/@Jfv/7P733//N3/8/Xd//P3bH379j9//9vH3/6x/@PW/ye//4Q//vvv9b//wX3/9qx9@87v/@Y8ff2w2m49G2TjcazwaKenjTxZkodo7z9I411maJzvi4KuvHrXN141HOpvSXz@4dn05FX/b@FkifT@Ihjsr7roaf934WT9OfZU6PHBHx2HgV19OAj8b7XSTG/pKeldDPCXyHS8O43QnHfYfdNe7rW630@psrD7EGDt@fYVnDMJYZjtpMBxljV81HrUtLY/alvR@7E9Ff8ir7TafPXu2/2y/ie89FWUqxYUUo1QNdptB5Ksbl/bd3BvFY/WoLfcaf1fdx47tXd777M2@fjeQH@z9Z71vl9/v2gGZ8kZR4MlQLBmayESl2o5M8n6IgVkQR3p@4Jvn3Y4dRpfCTJwftZaN7KAL0H36av5@FufpajEC14t7S9J4mMrxGOdpx51W38wP9iNlBz2593SBC0Fsb@Jq/mZA53EdqEmx9@qL@aHXga/iYpj5MD/kQx5nqhhiPswPkUlS8tYOrH81P3yUZYneabeHQTbK@64Xj9uBjr0kaR8kyUGcquc5KAmDSOl2P4z77bHU2MDiXXfsN/eG5cf552DhJAgrESg/88BH7VJwMftKpCoE67w4aopsmihcj@VQtZNo2LTrDeQ13XdWuzerXZdu1KV/1Nl71N@7GCnSaFE7WPFKRsMca0GTOnviUbs/8/BEyDAYRruseHuNo9gPBoHyxYmXxX2Vis52S3RXuh2M3GvQ0oEWUgxVpFIZOkmeJrFWoiZaIrTPExMwGGP7gdQiiycy9bXQU/ByrBv1CdlIZo1Hecis2MMDlqrjz0HYQKUq8hTOV/RVhg2IA8NMmqfzJInT7JbZXii1bu75MpNC9mH8pEfS8bnT4zhp7sX998rLnDgNiHt@fdefuw4zLvAgN@Zifg0XZ8OcALdP0pYIIhFnI2x0Ahurd6oTKLk8iFPhq0EQEStl5Itc8ynQeToTRX/qG9Zu4zATIxyJxrHjrD0ZZQK3VTTMRpoeKFOF2xM8VWFg6uPklBjDYYDp@CLyQ@xd4TCw4LUKp/zUjIfTyPq6JPOhugmyKSQAnxIjFW7jYhTQs7ww95UWYxlNoQEaZstTGBYRudApv5AXfsQ490bYLnwKKzasLn0bRINUkjPzsjylyb5yBfPvIpWRDo0R2GEBE3xEj2SjsgQwBBPVH8U6A9eGSl1ptgjaC0jS2rXjcQqWO31I4L6CH8q1DmRkzw0rLxoZIifVaqrMqqXjdcAvx3OWLd/cO09kFOjRbetiWeXnmd1dnPLS7@XH6VW1XhpfY4330vHazb2zu@mEOdEq45Xyj46XhLmm/5p7rz/21dUndxgGiUyzQYiz5/lZWs0v/FGeXlUbYgGHxYL5ORQPlvrt/fcyjZSogApNfdiQY5IziDvJGJSCzh/aOAxIGAIStTE0EwoRD8gMuo23cS4giALqwSJaqk2LPxn//SGHCJIaGc0JslYh0bUBDRpQPsKMI0K8NOgrkkIxntZUPo6vis3zNdHfatSHzMKD0uW3GlhqBBlPFcwl9sHTRX9q7IAuaANfcMEjzORqCGlXoYwDmULzYqNhUMEw0Bnup1MyzLQyuKXAQ7IoQT@V6dRt9CI9oQUzO422z0oEOxLnGTsYYmpfGW3E5ivzjT2KT6Kp1m3DuhUqw8ED/PFOL4oTKCHWwvRhGGtNlFfzi6/4gbSOmaUBB8XnAhX2S@IQFu9aiSEsXWRVgJzsvEJOJhPXoAg3TofQOfNBwLboIDMYFEc1P602hXnbLD34s9LOLWrNRZwEnjVp1qLZZX8eKihOQNjglb0y8qKkN6IPBeSdnVWBmObei3hCJz9JQbYYxjHsLtmw6JapOsP6cBKG8sPzE6a@@HbJhDo0a@71ap9aooRILaEyz10yW42hbb7C457aq8JFLBlsJDqgXb0qLm9d@fnrQyM7uBDlTMO9OA6XrW/skJllrnk4XBu0arpkQuHiQNBzg6BKr7dsfYOIm3uXFTKe42WaBV5Iyx3EYaiMgyeTUNxYSgOcBjHwzFxYNFqADiNhdcmK5BhwdPk5n9fOuQQnxdDgI04HVokGP@BZpF9R4byLuVqcpEM4q4984yHZPwR5IfQh5W8Mjiyn6XJaXJuGc9UEDwBcGr3j80PzwN6YMBZM1fHiQw8BMoIsz9TDVmO/mLAPqYejWj6M7ciTw2Mz9LlKYR3voushG@PKSdWVQ0xAbaB1bvxHZ3t7C88QAAOwx6m6hnGI6EZ3ZWXVmH3clO/JUSUwDfBhWK3Tac2tc66SjNQkxcROB@Z8QECZjJmZsGb@bJolcdldgZlKya2GsHLwO0J6HuAmY/MYD43URMhxH6yB1xGrzhSmRWhvBBQSKrNBD9iLcaTZWqsklfcBRhgqOQzWI0MowoqVHUOAW3MgtNxPtZX3jcSTyWWPDnAY45hYjHhS4w7DrTNI@LwVgxUgqIv9G41yG6/5AHzsbpgD@ITT29DR7NJtQn2VJo3ikNYWfioH2YzNdBvHiHSNB8oYKgMkA6MKT6UZkDFAdxQD1wtIJmRLhhXUGaqMoUs8AAbHHcI@@BcHS8cgBmlsQBRtEhw6Pjy/YFZ5Uo/MKoQb8igMrgjbQwAipXxDCr5VWoupHSRLg10hI1wzmjBGEKgTcgC/Kov4BBPhidS1qjnTRX5j3XGAAE@JB5QSeVguQgZ56RkitIjAWp9Z/T7zOoDw3W57Mux2ELgVvCh9MduUBelgxkCUC1nOiI38ZUUaAh@Ed26jeUTICWyJmB/YEYI0yXEheHYVwY1WayJ6uxJ4SmYltljObS7H93fsqO3Hnm4b3NeGlq@3o7W17a6b@IPm3tFUEIYhyid0aKzsQgMxhjDHvH2WgkYvSYOQjMR6XdwOhQ89gmyFEznVLE4T8z3tzqJP@nx/DGRIiiaHQ3gxDdtR2zEEAjEIi0SJxo2tgSgnKaL3qfBCyh2AW7xg0xiKZovR7XBkBQTbIaC6LDNFsvOk8rtPr@Mw58M0D@SDLiC6ZqoU6WrtMEGjRxLN4SVhXXvc1pv7ymOaKEL11S301BJzn8i@iAewUimE7qkfsGPgcyipY98JA8mRvHGbhZKWslJiwGTON38JfNsRR@QnGcPjBp0GjTURDfjojWTgCU6@wqeO4VboDp0q@KpCBdfmwfNoOVCZifwhhKxG@L6I68HQ6zjwZZ/cwyND9G1iXsXEHD0WeMghskMj0T0T4tDhjGa2l8uUNI5UbpqYeKHMIhCFxabdxi3m@U@TA@wJxM5EXXUQbFKJSuIeHUPLnkOLDEhA2YWsoI44@1MoA4jkQbfucDmHKVFcxFo9Qaliqy/igVZeDB6qmojuwJbDdqQZS7140F1bwWkMlX5IygOEas06dD0tzI6xODb9N8B3V2qKSNQLQnahxgdZv3@YsbgEY4IdGYQphiOBxYnZmdl8Rkv0IYBjzmVxOCYJLa1oUXvi7erxhRFHLa5q9DhgFnU0siTbzHGj4gwS83E@@4xdAmGFHkWfOh8Oi3CaZITqKzYvd/sJhuqGEmImP3MdRJS9bZcud4aWimKDv4LIp7OfzhA1G9WYk1Kl9UwkJQJhgS7Nk8Sr4vGWKYRKTWYvU7fnuws6jKmp5b7tMi9kpJ2XrtiP1Wh8Xy/d@KhPN11y1O0hpbJKZHdQoFcxlGmfDKxXhkBs@A1e9uKc5Alk0EyKjQYICXBOdnRMiROpIXzYONku8tSNB8tomYYAiq52cyeLr6axKz33fUJU@UPP1WbPr6OAgVbGnuSCxtmcx5IFhyomP@PRqVJCuPrE2a4CIEFaIDVMPYOuaxmEZFkNGyD4wL@pUDeSDmRn6ZOSMB@PZBiaJ53aT3z2nBtZNoVS7SxvrO2UCPVzL@PDxRJ0NwKimklOLKrepyPwGU2Dd7nJVMQwworOAmGeUyYWCRSZjGEySh7HCZ37Lsh9N85Spe4dIgQK/N31zeZegedIVkp6KhR0xzM4uqermuRWOlYdxszqDP/gTJcLNSzxOBnlqTb67JFi9nVRAiwgYrWYTXy5t9sHmGYsBiKbe/vFpTHePTjEJIZAxjABEJhGtexYEZ4jZ0rgFPYpNIZgHqNWicGlz9cZGOBKP@6b9G9z7/zilewXvqPSSk5VKpU6FBKqCdl7Qg9wLSUDresuaWw1QsLVcljksVhE2OX04xqpRbgujJCVFQnB3BCl6BE@ISdD5kKGmioSNqqgGhxnPHu0EUHYe5GaMsWQcfxvCjiHVKcrHrzAHVrIrFNj0SS4Ctp@ACGTUzj6sG3X@orX@squBfd@@Kp28M/Ia0JYsLwpg9FaO4uYhtR2blR7QlLW5k22SdjqfsLEGWavCzpS2Gq4XqcG9ESUm9RKWJNTgwcAsm88CBOpHGxWpm0gXrlISifM1P/KJPty6xXH9mlGI/HRQO0TU447Kcpxx3aUOOVqJ3yAqZTZfdbOEU@nqTaZjtgyNCUzUMuhEARy8SjTOIbCAsK53og/NPfOTk4uSksiDp6eHXM2RM8ITRlbjIHeWktsuA9bEcaSxPoTpvTuZGPdnHZXVjYcTrAsCogfwneNmZd@HLRlX7c7K26ns7beXl3d2ljtrhB/0@C6iAmEl8YT3yosAoSI9RFmI/Q5f0MZqo3v//WH3/zuh1//Ez2UJUfgf4YYYLWOQ2PqxADnOTKkpIbDGQoD9SmG4@fWKpyB2SmxihQvVZC62sPL1Wvy2tne3HboxtwTu0VA8cKwzeKTHVFOmDHzdGKMXaBJ1jURCt75icFoLeVxgEVzSpYUhBzlWuW3wSAdDzKqwoIODZjNII7PrxDktveOPBb/U0dJJt6tTKtJjz2gyK8FufPyEj@2bBnJeOeHFdSLQ9/A75yyJVkeyUzZ9FOBAfExgI@FrYZHaUG/YWJNQbVWEQsRQRXdGVxgolPmggwWlkEKIQMQRrw91jMsA3ROTXKCK8Z03Gv07UhC@GG7bDqCwphBoEIfokGJjrHkcrCOi8yVSfZg@CCEPmk7rK8YlUNX1df0KBj3SAacnbolmrijTnAVZHpeGZcd6SDMrozHfvbq4ps7/PswuxqPLRzh6zvGf8gcKxnmEd9mVeVs2fjJzSTwhyrTZvibmzfm4x3o7tPFmKUcqHUiOGCZM@a6lCrUEv54QE6rCPhNxgwAHY4WrkWyaJgyLRcbABqXPHmeMy/Pnzm9SyfNQ0AAfhK@Ia0nTcSlIPG7ViMqmRSZEZbOIk9ULSpqBdzKHV6cmWXrycwyhXlfi4sz2kptglnwUkHxOZFsKZ5n44ybhPiT0r2nRgycQOCNuFWCPNKOOMQlZSCDjJhyMJIJGZfuOgeCU7jYm2w2a/XJZrAdcQr19AJot5HsUz4znEvJ@ztEA5iVK76f1oW5DPlAfigKp/QZjGue5yQHtJq1BpwusO1HJj3dp/YjQjtUuWAmcPqbu2aIgjJt98mytHvbsM8sSy@ZjxkrN7hdLbByMz9cpppCMXFAGZ1brH8iU6lHwcCGC1995YAsJ4SNhzkwBZA7I4T3ZPN811fjmKI6N79qe9prV2yYwdFlzNGwAJkOnTHMtQxzBi4GMD8wLTylKcdxzKUl5hPoRTTxsHKGy@2j/KALodDtA9pym4vbzT3@43oOOEFYUlOfaVJSzD4yAuzkdqF6ip9NRy170DbxM7TqGqKtPxXGfl5VvS7nlCZWwEkQ1Pt6Du7eZOL/RBk/MwFIKb9l@b9l6b7O9mel@ygoClg1ua7XWXdF70@S0psNt8tiOR@iXbg4HKZjaUgPHjgjV4G5nhxT3gbSP1Jh0s6SsF3ATAhZ2RhsIJoc91Pyg6KW1XlK2FcZ8PJEUeMTiXodNNbzGLPBL3PUBL96toEmXl7Tkp6XG49MGtQ7OHhty9oaNjIohbpKhb0GOsRJFVWuT0j0XZ0InzTZddpggogwmvN1Q5aeD3gL3GIcWpTuTFWjefcG3GbjkLKQ1MNA1dUWiZaplXLAf/max5/gTChswgOG8iMn4wt5WWiXi1yKuU1XFhHNETgV8N4d/KK7j/@/O/SDeKyNmQ/4mqXuDjZ@VgNGnZcvVNoX5zn1rt7Xc/KxHPrF2QRiCzbP9HQMgN1taSYqiiKsCLYFVFU5EQuUZFEI4tqOZdU36hqGXLxQsFNTfX@WoMXUWJ7CdkNhbKLH1OkytgzxVdV/qgZ5ONuCYuqCXI6ai1/r1PQwZSzBl6XKwDeLjJkRVXNc5pqfQ32t8zknNk@WGEr4h/k4smHO7Qe72HpjT5Gi2qUKMcUO8yLBIzNv9Ph6d0sefjjcHx@/nB4xqTtkOoOICp0m@J/t8epZ05vJ8EpQKIe9fHuvV6XlegdHYFjuU27FsxgPFvaF9KgbOpmxVDjWXnQF6NAS1H6ppm7jmeqnOaXHqKHbte0@t2r4sg2dT16@PlVvvjl7EXPZi8mFepvkMDGcq7mKCjrani8CMVaJ2TokdpuOcKOiuFUFxeem@7ZmYYVW8IUydRtFYzrlGdwvJP/p2cenx4Nv1zsHV/ey3Q1tEPu@krmtZZ7GE1NnbMLnAr6DtmZF8UGSAA/xk8VJotjpfKOmQOWQ4HrbDVOWWGH5IgrjWI3Sq7dXz/3evUHfCwN/93DSO1t9t9ofvr189s7feL/xzfsX@ydr0Tg5yJ3N@MnV1tv@@cGWfJu@9MPn173r@F0v7A7evn23/WbN7JBQXBDlRK9ampeoyc2BhFXV4vDwUBxJHw5QHJxDYYuDcBsvZWSFqLPtfqkAnb52ulH2JH/WWanvr7M@WD8/G4@n6dSXm4fXeni4//HJq4PL77yjs48b716eXfS9zY2N7zrH33re8zP1rrv1YTxdG5LhhaQkmTbR3CDnsJ9qsYsN9uJBVg0BVqEu2Yd/ZgasrY710YfL9YPLXnPvmBpyyReAuL8yhFyQ7kOJikfDeOXkFAWjXL34dGu5GueZuibQkqawfgbkjiTMeuhsL8kBeubetjvWvjHn5/AiwEDbzvMY1FDD3LVqmz5sp@rDdg6LHllHZg6XpCMHpGw9rp/mdnr82jvw4m4SjQ4uorXeiw8X/ZPj8eDb67Un38SXvcvOlXp76l9uX15/M/x4dnNxeJn88ghGkmuL9gnG7i20grOiPpfAZioUT3BSZyqwXiYThiJizpZtRvGsfHABPg@Vrrq7laZIIZChwZNlwrHUEeqF9m34YrOF9IH9GCKyRFxKLd0/B3fx9XjXY/tzj@h0VLSLGeQBi1Om1yumRohmWgC36lLy2XL65Pr1q5W33X4y9WAqO91tGMs3tp2IK/ZgDPcFAZtNAkicyaSZ5xfG8coYR/JRR0oV9XEXFjcF7KBU@3VJ5sYXq5J6N9xYf/X6u2T/sLnXLOxAE/g7CQ3epHRhlxoq86woZ/xEOihtLm9y5X74YCAILCoV4Yu/gd/ubq9u2jSwzZ0/i6mmsq9GgYG3nMOgCKGz5RiixMXTJzfG31PnJqXWRzKoO7nb6elr7Wpv5PbHyh3lbUYs7b4RqfqLJtNEcaqt7KyhzhjHA6mTmB@t6Xz2c18mVGq@KN9prGxiAU@YUID48dRgLDnMAUr60MPzILqiMJrgqK/6@ZBLBGOVSWt/ScXCMJ6YKCCGRtM6ilN8ROFM845TNO/goVgdiJCfXPawceY5DzXpJEsDPawWEnKsCRkYm@TvRNmetjyFV8goe009Q4VlcEXjSE5/mgzK0@v@TX6y/@3migGjF7EvC35FjFqc6i3RzBr3g1FOXZCU9yE2Dmv1gHMERioDWKvGUO/ntBaO2jluY3WjkG13ZgdfrOy/PFk5/e7t0eXz89fNvRMKBmv1kaXv4gBM2nLMLZWMRhdhSU4voywD856dZKtXHJNVqF23Y9BgO0gRmBvRXl1ByGGgML365KVBki0xd@tffIY3XnL@6iw5OXoJB3Ry@zt@7I/IpQQRkEOQVYncpwcnJ6f3O@slGqQcDXQD3joPp5@m6jN9BV875oOz1nUWfUdQ9x3GVRBGZ@bVnKp9h8dA2cITmrA9VWL2ddbPZu3iJp5eUxKufXB62q782Hr7jWmJw9Zi3zlwOgCo/NWwDA47a9ZQT0WJt8HZq2U4myhign46RWARVIzf9WJTyBlNl/RKPbRl3RJSrJu6JvUQ3C9ehuqsrIgPuQz5FUdaYRnPblXIRSpVjUrn9NSxdK61VzqrzpG8wpFzhtW5kPpK2w/NPbojNH8AGbhjPyzh5dotvFy7zdF8mpV1Ir@EmWs/gZlrX6zb7598@Db3@1n@Ib43UFwT3OVxLr3ESeXNiKRdNHlLTVYIhNzWgOdDKrb8JN5Q369z/PS7i@rKnKM1Ec09@t49VjfZfRyJ/dYkGhhnOY4IBqBnmrF3w0dOk05swpMKmbaN8jE888aWdQUFmCC@YyNfTHfd5oDe1bbFco6lcNHwNPdqc@53Vmf3QnjoKeFsT5XF9jdkxJ@ahjXOGOPbLfNaCr0CY99qsTlB4n1PbG/cvr/klsrmdTBWMe9tdX21u7G5ujEbX5j@Nxa82q9DWM/kIM7q2HaBc1t@F0@gnWGccEKC4MbhzLvHn@rD/Sx@165JVrrtW3lOsUGn43A9ao7/3Vn@MzNN4Yr5uHI3H3uL2WiCMHYLrswym//rXdy7YLxYhJrMUVuAkbdlEZetRZ1QDnsq1xuMSfA67dX2ZpsWdw7phfBlcgdUxL1r/Bp4pqn0JL2sasiBIQrSz3q@6STEox@fK3pB5UIOd@nZv@iu8NMBlmmbfM3rIyQPaglnZmbMgrxys3j4vp6oftU7pOjtqnanu7K2tbb@OIx2FTw1hVZPz47NG6t1q7eyXesboQzgi5PTV04QBPOP4Va6qrcniz3eEYLyTnd1a2sN5rmca2DBrIU28vsyhznEUzfLzZnCJW@RX4MVcvE1Kk97Yd53c9hdysrHlLIeKz@QbZ4NPjr4rxfhnxNbOnKXtcy@sfNt3n1Bo0lCgBSGobK90D4hfjl97AM3@7vO6trm1vbK5srGZqezubbd2VzfIv2gCS1x/PbAOJ3SsNd2OXOEUIyAEgPBRxwB94WVWxdfTtV6d6O7trkNjV5d2Vjf2lrtrlVEHcU5l0cKi@SKWpq2pO@c@yBDe2wwjrkfxMJIEpS/SGqUwNjUXcmFthqJhKjbEdUrzstLZRyrqMyjZh3ff29eGIi8d57EYrGpTj4OIJvvsK9tbKPxJHXFk7jfpzaHanL5mle9IaMXqhuYIgWC4mubjJNcp7eJlfOLVw@Lpg8oM8mz9RtLG7Jr/p5yZO3etknXmwPQjweIN3eHCJru0Y53OwSTsDSVgz32O6cLP75hZIF6jAQFI7DqO5@f7t/YVv7JeGtr@3Jtph@syrSKB9x2WrQHm2rYIJzat0S0MctNwQhgJBP4XvOaaFa8gqXND4xo85oZFXqkyFSoEKeMqR7QQvAbkKnCdMQvLeqAmowguUEm@ml8pbjdkCaNAn4FlSoFNmlPz25xKwmF2dRsopUy6a8woN/poPcVIu79UvprS46lvg8Y5bucg6VOL5FRcoEeUXYAsILRDJ@i/yKWAt2JfQ/DtpKx6R6rMcWFYARItxRRBE9g6Kp8tQ10a0nR/E1GdCd5GKoiX5fa4phN2JkXzYZQNJEBFzx0G6fU05YUb1rdEsZWJaJlNdTFN6nvrJv2VRg6oexrK7Zp2x@ndKdNukRN9VqcBZTSoMYh@v2qxHazUr6iUTRjhLFR8Xpfba3XoVG9iGdDbHqj9qBFOZ0bYwkekPd@KPap7/uV7HM10rLA/vgJpWPYGwrza0GNB@Y3YShYpHPsx2n08BNtB0uCfPuO3HJe0ybv60aJtk5r3Y7iOaW//0TtkYv1wXp3pH1fgCSRiqw1MTLdlPT2Mzw/whjIWD@3L9TQT@RQr3nxns@DUnWKXkxf4fBC/bBWdaRX7a2Ec4uDNKNNJ0VfeZL0@9A2CXCDzS3nbX5@p0Wa2ajmVa@jwozEKdsK@x4HsKCN1MxrQgUL2bqEARUcONwg5lg5n@2liQy6Mq/VuI3DAb8FO1AqLGyVqQ3TC@S@b3fWMgMGqTKvfZLsjZXRZZNQnprC2V9@1e0vv@r2//hX3dr0Y4f824f0643NZvN/AQ).

**Explanation:**

```python
žZ              # Push builtin constant "http://www."
.•‹Ìe¨¹w•       # Push compressed string "stroustrup"
’.ŒŒ/C++.ŠÎ’    # Push dictionary string ".com/C++.html"
J               # Join the three strings on the stack together to an URL
 .w             # Pop and download the HTML content of this URL
'"¡            '# Split it on double quotes '"'
   ü2           # Get all overlapping pairs
     ʒ          # Filter this list of pairs by:
      `         #  Pop and push the strings of the pair to the stack
       žX       #  Push builtin "http://"
         žY     #  Push builtin "https://"
           ‚    #  Pair them together
            Å?  #  Check for both whether the second string starts with these substrings
              à #  Pop and check if either of the two is truthy
      s         #  Swap so the first string is at the top of the stack
       …aØ·=    #  Push dictionary string "a href="
            Å¿  #  Check if the first string ends with this substring
      *         #  Check whether both were truthy
     }€         # After the filter: map over each overlapping pair:
       θ        #  Leave just the last/second string of each
                # (after which the list of URLs is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `’.ŒŒ/C++.ŠÎ’` is `".com/C++.html"`; `…aØ·=` is `"a href="`; and `.•‹Ìe¨¹w•` is `"stroustrup"`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 218 bytes

```go
import(."io";."net/http";."regexp")
func f(){r,_:=Get("http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html")
b,_:=ReadAll(r.Body)
for _,e:=range MustCompile(`<a[^>]+href="(http.+?)"`).FindAllStringSubmatch(string(b),-1){println(e[1])}}
```

[(you cannot) Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LU_LTsMwEDyTr4h8spXUUW8oEBBUghMXeqxK66ROYuGX3LUCivolXCIkbhz5Gfia2i2X3R3t7OzMx2dnpm_LmlfW8VQxob88tLPL3z-hrHGAKRIGXVGkORQ9gI2z4x1_s4gkrddN2mIyunxTVo8cMIqcsiiGYaB7cMaH4i1tjCoWWUZ7UDLc1ZH-zNnuTkrs6L3ZvQcx49JNzsvKMR28PIXThVFWSI6312z1crPOesfbCuH4g2a3BG0JfRA6qizBCd0tfa0YND3enyCuST6bk9EGAFJjvpqvyeFwTvhzMh8TY5KOyUWIkfyvpuncjw)

Prints all URLs to STDERR, separated by newlines.

ATO doesn't allow web requests.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>49</s> <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```
`s≠ĿꜝǓ≥₂.•⅛/C++.°¤`¨U`₁(ṅ•s?://[^"]+)`Ẏ
```

[no point Trying it Online because web requests are disabled (if I've done things correctly - they were accidentally enabled once. Big brain)!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgc+KJoMS/6pydx5PiiaXigoIu4oCi4oWbL0MrKy7CsMKkYMKoVWDigoEo4bmF4oCicz86Ly9bXlwiXSspXCI+YOG6jiIsIiIsIiJd)

Example output from Crosshatch.

*-8 by remembering `https://www.` is automatically appended to links if not present when calling `¨U`*

*-2 by not including the closing `"` and `>` in the regex*

[image]

### Explained

```
`s≠ĿꜝǓ≥₂.•⅛/C++.°¤`¨U`₁(ṅ•s?://[^"]+)`Ẏ
`s≠ĿꜝǓ≥₂.•⅛/C++.°¤` # stroustrup.com/C++.html
¨U # GET request
`₁(ṅ•s?://[^"]+)` # <a href="(https?://[^"]+)
Ẏ # All regex matches
```

Answer (score 3):

## [hyperscript](https://hyperscript.org/), <s>130 101</s> 62 bytes

```ruby
def f()fetch"C++.html"put it into me return<[href^=ht/>'s@href
```

This program [must be run from the site's root](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13626/58974) to avoid CORS issues. There is a snippet below that uses a CORS proxy to do the same without running on a different domain.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/hyperscript.org@0.9.8"></script>
<script type="text/hyperscript">
def f()fetch"//corsproxy.io/?https://stroustrup.com/C++.html"put it into me return<a[href^=ht/>'s@href

init put f().join("<br />") into <body />
</script>
```

Ungolfed:

```
def f()
  fetch "C++.html"
  put it into me
  return @href of <a [href^="http"] />
end
```

Usually hyperscript is very verbose, but it's perfect for a challenge like this. This function fetches the HTML, throws it into the `<body>`, selects all `<a>` whose `href` starts with `http`, and returns each's `href`. I was somehow able to get rid of almost every single piece of whitespace in the program because hyperscript doesn't need whitespace before or after parenthesis, string, query literal, or attribute literal tokens.

Answer (score 3):

### ****C#, 221 bytes****

**Golfed**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;var r=await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("https://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html");foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(r,"<a.\\n?href=\"(https?.*?)(?=\")"))Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
```

**Ungolfed**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var r = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("https://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html");
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(r, "<a.\\n?href=\"(https?.*?)(?=\")"))
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 88 bytes

```
Import[s="https://www.stroustrup.com/";s<>"C++.html","Hyperlinks"]~Select~StringFreeQ@s&
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby 3 + [`nokogiri`](https://nokogiri.org/), 152 bytes

```ruby
require'open-uri'
require'nokogiri'
p Nokogiri::HTML.parse(URI.open("https://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html").read).css("a[href^=http]").map{_1.attr"href"}
```

Outputs an array of strings of URLs. Doesn't assume anything about the structure of `<a>`s that might be deviously crafted to fudge regular expression approaches. We cannot use `Nokogiri::XML` because it doesn't correctly parse HTML URL query parameters.

## Ruby 3, 113 bytes

```ruby
require'open-uri'
URI.open("https://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html").read.scan(/<a[^>]+href="(http.+?)"/).map{p *_1}
```

Outputs a string on each line. Uses a regular expression approach which might be fooled in some cases (e.g. `<a style=">" ...`), although it produces the same sequene of URLs.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>79</s> 78 bytes

Must be run from the root folder of the site ([consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13626/58974)), returns a `Promise` containing an array of URLs ([consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12327/58974)).

```javascript
async _=>(await(await fetch`C++.html`).text()).match(/(?<=href=").+:.+(?=")/g)
```

Here's a snippet that uses a proxy to allow it to bypass the site's CORS policy:

```js
f=

async _=>(await(await fetch`//corsproxy.io/?https://stroustrup.com/C++.html`).text()).match(/(?<=href=").+:.+(?=")/g)

f().then(a=>console.log(a.join`\n`))
```

Comment: Note that this uses lookbehind in the regex which is only supported in V8.

Comment: @Jacob No it's not. See https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind

Comment: @Neil Huh, I could have sworn I saw somewhere that it wasn't supported. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/) `-d:ssl`, 106 bytes

Dirty solution which might break on a different webpage.

```
import httpclient,re
echo newHttpClient().getContent"http://stroustrup.com/C++.html".findAll re"htt[^""]*"
```

[Don't Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3VbSSbopVcXGOUuyCpaUlaboWN7Mycwvyi0oUMkpKCpJzMlPzSnSKUrlSkzPyFfJSyz2Aos5gUQ1NvfTUEuf8vBIgRwmk2kpfv7ikKL8USJQW6CXn5-o7a2vrZZTk5ijppWXmpTjm5CgUpYKURscpKcVqKUFshFq8AEoDAA)

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/) `-d:ssl` + [Nimquery](https://github.com/GULPF/nimquery), 201 bytes

Should work on any possible webpage.

```
import htmlparser,httpclient,nimquery,re,xmltree
for e in newHttpClient().getContent"http://stroustrup.com/C++.html".parseHtml.querySelectorAll"a[href^='http://'],a[href^='https://']":echo e.attr"href"
```

[Don't Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VU87DoJAEO09xWYbNC5La0gsDA29JcGE4CAk-3N2iHoWGxJj4008grdxQRqb-bx5817e_WE6_Sp4fEy9V7wcnj018ebz7rSzSKwlrVyFHlC0RK5WHRgS4efcA94EgrhqRQiwaCwyYJ1hBi55oGYTdbmSJ6DMGgoLHyXSJPGEtg-ld7K2OsnWazn6cDk55WGUk_weFNRkcacUr4oWoTlso1kjKsUf5CeMp1C3loGsiJCPZ_4LNOca5v4F)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) + [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), 220 bytes

### Golfed version(220 bytes)

```scala
object A{def main(args:Array[String])=org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(scala.io.Source.fromURL("https://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html").mkString).select("a[href]").eachAttr("abs:href").toArray.toList.map(_.toString).foreach(println)}
```

### Ungolfed version

```scala
import java.net.URL
import scala.io.Source
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import org.jsoup.select.Elements

object UrlExtractor {

  def downloadHtml(url: String): String = {
    Source.fromURL(url).mkString
  }

  def extractUrls(html: String): List[String] = {
    val doc: Document = Jsoup.parse(html)
    val elements: Elements = doc.select("a[href]")
    elements.eachAttr("abs:href").toArray.toList.map(_.toString)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // println("This is in UrlExtrator object.")
    val url = "https://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html"
    val html = downloadHtml(url)
    // println(html)
    val urls = extractUrls(html)

    println("List of URLs:")
    urls.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 40 bytes

```bash
curl -L stroustrup.com/C++.html|retina p
```

File `p`:

```
s`a.

S`href="
G`tp
".*
```

The tricky things are

1. `a` and `href` seperated by a newline
2. two links on the same line

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=7VzJdttMdl6HT1Fhn7at_AQoUrPalg8lT_JvDZZk-Xdv3EWgSMICARgFiKKTnJN3yDKb3iTPkGWeI8s8Sb57qzBwkmyfTm_Sffq3QKKqcOvWHb47gP_2H6nKgkj--c__nmcDZ_c_9Z-k22hc_mmUqsGzZuP1n7Kk0XT_oWFu21F__u_3__V0lI3Dg8bTkZI-_mRBFqqDyyyNc52lebIvjn755WnbfN14qrMp_fWDW9eXU_GPjb9LpO8H0XB_3d1S4z80_q4fp75KHR64r-Mw8KsvJ4Gfjfa7yR19Jb2bIZ4S-Y4Xh3G6nw77T7pb3Va322l1tjfWMMaO31rnGYMwltl-GgxHWeOfG0_blpanbUt6P_anoj_k1Z41X716dfjqsInvPRVlKsWFFIYbQeSrO5f23TwYxWP1tC0PGv9U3ceO7V3e--zNvv48kF_t_Ve998vvd-2ATHmjKPBkKJYMTWSiUm1HJnk_xMAsiCM9P_Dj627HDqNLYSbOj9rMRnbQFeg-fzd_P4vzdKMYgevFvSVpPEzleIzztOPOq2_mB_uRsoNePHq5wIUgtjdxNX8zoPO4DdSk2Hv1xfzQ28BXcTHMfJgf8jWPM1UMMR_mh8gkKXlrB9a_mh8-yrJE77fbwyAb5X3Xi8ftQMdekrSPkuQoTtXrHJSEQaR0ux_G_fZYamxg8a479psHw_Lj_HOwcBKElQiUn3ng03YpuJh9I1IVgnVeHDVFNk0UrsdyqNpJNGza9Qbylu47G927ja5LN-rSP-ocPO0fXI0UabSoHax4J6NhjrWgSZ0D8bTdn3l4ImQYDKNnrHgHjZPYDwaB8sWZl8V9lYrOXkt017sdjDxo0NKBFlIMVaRSGTpJniaxVqImWiK0zxMTMBhj-4HUIosnMvW10FPwcqwb9QnZSGaNp3nIrDjAA5aq4-9A2EClKvIUzlf0VYYNiCPDTJqn8ySJ02zFbC-UWjcPfJlJIfswftIj6fje6XGcNA_i_hflZU6cBsQ9v77r712HGRd4kBtzMb-Gi7NhToDbZ2lLBJGIsxE2OoGN1fvVCZRcHsSp8NUgiIiVMvJFrvkU6DydiaI_9Q1rt3GciRGOROPYcdaejDKB2yoaZiNND5Spwu0JnqowMPVxckqM4TDAdHwR-SH2rnAYWPBWhVN-asbDaWR9XZL5UN0F2RQSgE-JkQq3cTUK6FlemPtKi7GMptAADbPlKQyLiFzolF_ICz9inHsjbBc-hRUbVpe-DaJBKsmZeVme0mRfuYL5d5XKSIfGCOyzgAk-oqeyUVkCGIKJ6o9iDf86HCp1o9kiaC8gSWvXjscpWO70IYGHCn4o1zqQkT03rLxoZIicVKupMquWjtcBvxzPWbZ88-AykVGgR6vWxbLKzzO7uzjlpb_Ib9Obar00vsUaX6TjtZsHFw_TCXOiVcYr5d8cLwlzTf81Dz5866ube3cYBolMs0GIs-f5WVrNL_xRnt5UG2IBh8WC-TkWT5b67cMvMo2UqIAKTV1ryDHJGcSdZAxKQecPbRwGJAwBidoYmgmFiAdkBt3GpzgXEEQB9WARLdWmxZ-M__6aQwRJjYzmBFmrkOjagAYNKB9hxhEhXhr0FUmhGE9rKh_HN8Xm-ZrobzXqQ2bhQenyWw0sNYKMpwrmEvvg6aI_NXZAF7SBL7jgEWZyNYS0q1DGgUyhebHRMKhgGOgM99MpGWZaGdxS4CFZlKCfynTqNnqRntCCmZ1G22clgh2J84wdDDG1r4w2YvOV-cYexb1oqrVqWLdCZTh4gD_e6VVxAiXEWpg-DGOtifJqfvEVP5DWMbM04KD4XqDCfkkcw-LdKjGEpYusCpCTnVfIyWTiGhThxukQOmc-CNgWHWQGg-Ko5qfVpjBvm6UHf1XauUWtuYqTwLMmzVo0u-zvQgXFCQgbvLNXRl6U9Eb0oYC8s7MqENM8eBNP6OQnKcgWwziG3SUbFq2YqjOsDydhKD--PGPqi2-XTKhDs-ZBr_apJUqI1BIq89wls9UY2uYrPO6lvSpcxJLBRqID2tW74nLlyq8_HBvZwYUoZxruxXG4bH1jh8wsc83D4dqgVdMlEwoXB4JeGwRVer1l6xtE3Dy4rpDxHC_TLPBCWu4oDkNlHDyZhOLGUhrgNIiBF-bCotECdBgJq0tWJMeAo8vP-bJ2ziU4KYYG33A6sEo0-AnPIv2KCuddzNXiLB3CWX3jG2tk_xDkhdCHlL8xOLKcpstpcW0azlUTPABwafROL4_NA3tjwlgwVaeLDz0GyAiyPFNrrcZhMeEQUg9HtXwY25EXx6dm6GuVwjo-RNcaG-PKSdWVQ0xAbaB1bvxHZ29vF88QAAOwx6m6hXGI6EZ3fX3DmH3clF_IUSUwDfBhWK3Tac2tc6mSjNQkxcROB-Z8QECZjJmZsGn-7Jglcdldh5lKya2GsHLwO0J6HuAmY_MYD43URMhxH6yB1xEbzhSmRWhvBBQSKrNBD9iLcaTZWqsklfcBRhgqOQzWI0Mowor1fUOAW3MgtNzP2srHRuLJ5LJHBziMcUwsRjxpAUnNGW6dQcLnrRisAEFd7N9olNv4wAfgY3fDHMAnnK5CR7NLtwn1VZo0ikNaW_ipHGQzNtNtnCLSNR4oY6gMkAyMKjyVZkDGAN1RDFwvIJmQLRlWUGeoMoYu8QAYHHcI--BfHCwdgxiksQFRtElw6PT48opZ5Uk9MqsQbsijMLghbA8BiJTyDSn4VmktpnaQLA12hYxwzWjCGEGgTsgB_Kos4hNMhCdSt6rmTBf5jXXHAQI8JZ5QSmStXIQM8tIzRGgRgbU-s_pL5nUA4bvd9mTY7SBwK3hR-mK2KQvSwYyBKBeynBEb-cuKNAQ-CO_cRvOEkBPYEjE_sCMEaZLjQvDsJoIbrdZE9HYj8JTMSmyxnNtcju8f2FHbjz3dNrivDS3fakebm3tdN_EHzYOTqSAMQ5RP6NBY2YUGYgxhjnn7LAWNXpIGIRmJrbq4HQsfegTZCidyqlmcJuZ72p1Fn_T58RjIkBRNDofwYhq2o7ZjCARiEBaJEo0bWwNRTlJE71PhhZQ7ALd4waYxFM0Wo9vhyAoItkNAdVlmimTnReV3X97GYc6HaR7IB11AdM1UKdLV2mGCRo8kmsNLwrr2uK0395XHNFGE6qsV9NQSc_dkX8QTWKkUQvfSD9gx8DmU1LHvhIHkSN64zUJJS1kpMWAy55t_BL7tixPyk4zhcYNOg8aaiAZ89EYy8AQnX-FTx3ArdIdOFXxVoYJr8-B5tByozET-EEJWI3xfxPVg6G0c-LJP7uGpIXqVmFcxMUePBR5yiOzQSHTPhDh0OKOZ7eUyJY0jlZsmJl4oswhEYbFpd9nz_3I5wJ5A7EzUVQfBJpWoJO7RMbTsObTIgASUXcgK6oizP0MZQCQPWrnD5RymRHERa_UEpYqtvognWnkxeKhqIroPWw7bkWYs9eJJd3MdpzFUeo2UBwjVmnXoelqYHWNxbPpvgO9u1BSRqBeE7EKND7J-_zhjcQnGBDsyCFMMRwKLE7Mzs_mMluhDAMecy-JwTBJaWtei9sTV6vGDEUctrmr0OGAWdTSyJNvMcaPiDBLzcT77jF0CYYUeRZ86Hw6LcJpkhOorNi-3-gRDdUcJMZOfuQ0iyt62S5c7Q0tFscFfQeTT2U9niJqNasxJqdJ6JpISgbBA1-ZJ4l3xeMsUQqUms5ep1fnugg5jamq5b7vMGxlp560rDmM1Gj_WSzc-6tNNlxx1e0iprBLZHRXoVQxl2icD65UhEBt-g5e9OCd5Ahk0k2KjAUICnJMdHVPiRGoIHzZOtos8dePJMlqmIYCiq93cyeKbaexKz_2SEFX-0HO12fOHKGCglbEnuaJxNuexZMGhisnPeHSqlBCuPnG2qwBIkBZIDVPPoOtWBiFZVsMGCD7wbyrUnaQD2V_6pCTMxyMZhuZJ5_YTnz3nRpZNoVQ7yxtrOyVC_dzL-HCxBN2NgKhmkhOLqnd_BD6jafAud5mKGEZY0VkgzHPKxCKBIpMxTEbJ8zihc38Gcj-Ps1SpR8cIgQL_2dZO86DAcyQrJT0VCnrgGRzd01VNcisdqw5jZnWGf3Cmy4UalnicjPJUG332SDH7uigBFhCxWswmvlakgmlFmGYsBiKbB4fFpTHePTjEJIZAxjABEJhGtexYEZ4jZ0rgFPYpNIZgHqNWicGlz9cZGOBKP-6b9G_z4PLqnewXvqPSSk5VKpU6FBKqCdl7Qg9wLSUDresuaWw1QsLVcljksVhE2OX04xqpRbgujJCVFQnB3BCl6BE-ISdD5kKGmioSNqqgGhxnPHu0EUHYe5GaMsWQcfxvCjjHVKcrHrzAHVrIrFNj0SS4Cdp-ACGTUzj6sG3X-oXX-sWuBfd-_K528K_Ia0JYsLwpg9Fa-4uYhtR2blR7QlLW5k22SdjqfsLEGWavCzpS2Gq4XqcG9ESUm9RKWJNTgwcAsu88CBOpHGxWpm0gXrlISifM1P_KJPty6xXH9mlGI_HRQO0zU447K8pxp3aUOOdqJ3yAqZTZfdbOEU-nqTaZjtgyNCUzUMuhEARy8SjTOIbCAsK53og_NA8uzs6uSksijl5enHI2RM8ITRlbjIHeWktsuA9bEcaSxPoeU_pwsrFuTrvr69sOJ1gWBcQP4bvGzEs_Dtqyr9uddbfT2dxqb2zsbm9014m_aXBbxATCS-OJbxUWAULE-gizEfqcv6EM1fb__Mu_0vNYaAT-Z-gATOs4dLtOByCeI0PKZzicnDAon8I3fmStuBmYTRKXSOdSBYGrPbdcvSaqnb2dPYduzD2xW8QSbwzHLDTZF-WEGQtPh8WwBUpkvRIB4P2fjENr2Y4jLJpTnqQg5CTXKl-FgHQ8yKgACzo0EDbjNz66Qobb3mdyVvxPHSCZULeyqiYz9oSCvhZEzstL6NiyFSTjmNcqlBeHvkHeOSVKsjySmbKZpwL-4WMA9wozDWfSgmrDuppaaq0YFiJ4KhozuLZEp8y1GCwsgxTyBQyMUHusZ1gG1JyavAQXi-m4N-nbkYTcw2zZTARFMINAhT5Eg3IcY8mVYB0XSSuT58HwQQhV0nZYXzEgh5qqP9CjYNcjGXBiakUg8UCJ4CbI9LweLjvSQZjdGGf96t3Vrw-49mF2Mx5bJMLXD4z_mjlWMswj3mdV0WzZ-MndJPCHKtNm-Me7j-bjA8Du_jrMUg7UmhAcsMwZc0lKFWoJVzwgf1XE-iZZBmwOHwuvIlk0TIWW6wzAi0uePM-Zt5evnN61k-YhvD8_Cd-Q1pMm4lKQ-N2qEVVLiqQIS2eRIqoWFbXabeUJry7MsvU8Zpm9fKzF1QVtpTbBLHitoPicQ7YUz7NxxkNC_EnpvlAPBk4g8EbcJUHOaF8c45KSj0FGTDkayYSMS3eLY8ApvOtdNpuwurcPbF-cQz29ANptJPuczwznUvL-AdEAXOVi7_26MJccH8ivRc2UPoNxzcuc5IBWs9aAMwW288hkpvvUeURAh4oWzATOfHPDDFFQZuzurUi7q4Z9Z0V6yXzMWL_D7WqB9bv54TLVFIWJI0rmrLD-iUylHgUDGyn88osDspwQNh7mwNQ-HgwOvpDN811fjWMK6Nz8pu1pr12xYQZCl-FGw2JjOnSGL7cyzBmzGKz8xHTvlKYcxzGXkZjPnReBxFrlDJfbR_lVF0Kh20e05TbXtZsH_Mf1HHCCYKSmFtOkpJh9ZATEyZ1C9ew-m45a4qBtQmdo1S1EW98XwX5fQb0u55QhVoBIENTHeg7p3mXi_0QZvzP3R9m-Zam_ZZm-zt53ZfooHgpYNbmk19lyRe8vks2bjbTLOjkfol24OBymY2k0Dx44I1eBuZ4cU8oG0j9SYdLOkrBdwEwIWdkTbCCaHPdT8oOiltB5SbBXGfDyQlHPE4l6HTTWUxizcS9z1MS9erZ3Jl5ezpKelxuPTBrUOzr6YCvaGjYyKIW6yoJ9ADrESRUFrnsk-qEmhHtNdp02mCAijOb8oSFLzwe8BW4xDi2qdqag0Xx4A26zcUwJSGpfoMJqi0TLlEk51r_-wOPPcCYUMeEBQ_mN8_CFvCx0ykUuhdumIYuI5uCbanefj37fPcT_Px_7QTzWxswHfM1S9wAbv6v3os7LNyrti8uc2lYf6zn5WA794mwCsQWbZ9o5BsDutioTFfUQVgTb_amqdIgFSrKoAXFZx7LqV3ULQy7eKNipqX48S9BiVixPYbuhMDbHY0p0GVuG-KZqPVWDPJztPjElQa5EzYWudWp6mDKW4MtSZeCbRbLMiKo5LnPNz6GW1vl0E5snSwzl-sN8HNkwZ_XBLnbd2FOkqHapQkyxw7zI7cjMGz2_fbYrj78eH45P305PmNR9Mp1BRDVOE_fPtnf1rOnNZHgjKJTDXt4_6lUZud7RCRiW-5RW8SzGg4V9Iz1qhE5mLBWOtRfdADq0BHVeqqnbeKX6aU6ZMerldm2nz0oNX7ahy8nbD-fq468Xb2KueDG5UG-TFyaGcyFXUS1H2_NFIMYqMVuCxG7TEW5UFLeqoPjSNN7WLKzQCr5Qpm6j6EmnPMOqhotV5L-8-PbydPB-q3N08yh7tq0NYj9UMrdlzPN4YkqMTfhcwHfQ1qwoPkoS4CF-sjhLFDudX9UUqBwSXO-4YcoSKyw_RGEcq1F68-nmtd97NOh7YeA_O570LjY-b_SHn65fffa3v2z_-uXN4dlmNE6OcmcnfnGz-6l_ebQrP6Vv_fD1be82_twLu4NPnz7vfdw0OyQUF0Q50auW5iVqcnMkYVW1OD4-FifShwMUR5dQ2OIg3MZbGVkh6uytrKmu2t_5B6cbZS_yV531-v46W4Oty4vxeJpOfblzfKuHx4ffXrw7uv7NO7n4tv357cVV39vZ3v6tc_re815fqM_d3a_j6eaQDC8kJcm0ieYGOYf9VIZd7K0XT7JqCLAKNciu_ZUZsLkx1idfr7eOrnvNg1PqxSVfAOL-3hByRboPJSoeDeOVk1MUjHL14tOt5WpcZuqWQEuawvoZkDuSMOuhs7ck_eeZe3vuWPvGnF_CiwAD7TmvY1BDvXK3qm1asJ2qBds5LtpjHZk5XI2OHJCy-7x-mnvp6QfvyIu7STQ6uoo2e2--XvXPTseD97ebL36Nr3vXnRv16dy_3ru-_XX47eLu6vg6-eMJjCSXFe0TjN1b6AJnRX0tgc1UKF7gpC5UYL1MJgxFxJxd24fiWfng2nseKl01ditNkUIgQ4Mny4RjqSPUBu3b8MVmC-kD-zFEZIm4llq6fw3u4uvxM4_tzyOi01HRM8wgD1icMr1ZMTVCNNP9t1uXku-W0xe3H96tf-r2k6kHU9np7sFYfrSdRFysB2O4JQjYbBJA4kwmzTy_MI43xjiSjzpRqiiNu7C4KWAHZdlvSzK3f1iV1Ofh9ta7D78lh8fNg2ZhB5rA30lo8CalC7vUS5lnRSXjJ-mgjLm8y5X79auBILCoVH8v_gZ-u7u3sWPTwDZt_iqmcsqhGgUG3nIOgyKEzq5jiBJXL1_cGX9PTZuUVR_JoO7kVtPT19rV3sjtj5U7ytuMWNp9I1L1d0ymieJUW9lUQ00xjgdSJzE_WtP5HOa-TKjKfFW-zljZxAKeMKEA8eOpwVhymAOU9KGHl0F0Q2E0wVFf9fMhVwfGKpPW_pKKhWE8MVFADI2mdRSn-IjCmb4dp-jbwUOxOhAhP7lsX-PMcx5q0kmWBnpYLSTkWBMyMDbJ34my7Wx5Cq-QUfaa2oUKy-CKxomc_pwMyvPb_l1-dvh-Z92A0avYlwW_IkYtTvWCaGaN-9EopwZIyvsQG4e1esAlAiOVAaxVY6jtc1oLR-0ct7GxXci2O7ODH1b2P56tn__26eT69eWH5sEZBYO1-sjS13AAJm05ZkUlo9FFWJLTeyjLwLxnJ9nCFcdkFWrX7Rg02OZRBOZGtDfWEXIYKExvPXlpkGRLzN3WD5_hnZdcvrtIzk7ewgGdrX69j_0RuZQgAnIIsiqR-_Lo7Oz8cWerRIOUo4FuwFvn4fR-qr7TV_C1Yz44m11n0XcEdd9hXAVhdGZezana13cMlC08oQnbUyVm32T9btYubuLlLSXh2kfn5-3Kj221P5puOGwt9p0jpwOAyl8Ny-Cws2kN9VSUeBucvVmGs4kiJujnKQKLoGL8mhebQs5ouqRXas1WdEtIsWXqmtQ-8Lh4D6qzvi6-5jLktxtphWU8W6mQi1SqGpXO-blj6dxsr3c2nBN5gyPnDKtzJfWNth-aB3RHaP4AMnDHfljCy80VvNxc5WjuZ2WdyB9h5uZPMHM5iffp9pcXX9_nfj_Lv8aPBoprgs94nEvvb1J5MyJpF03eUpMVAiG3NeD5kIotP8Ubavl1Tl_-dlVdmXO0JqJ5QN-7p-oue4wjsd-aRAPjLMcRwQD0TDP2bvjIadKJTXhSIdN2UD6HZ97eta6gABPEd2zkh-mu2xzQu9G2WM6xFC4anuZBbc7jzsbsXggPvSSc7amy2P6RjPhL06vGGWN8u2veSKG3X-wLLTYnSLzvib3t1ftbql3Y420wVjHvbWNro7u9s7E9G1-Y1jcWvNoPQ1jP5CDO6th2gUtbfhcvoJ1hnHBCguDG8cxrx_e14H4Xv2vXJCvd9kqeU2zQ6Thcj5rjf3eW_8xMU7hiPq4_zMfeYjaaIIzdgiuzzOb_elePrhgvFqEmc9QWYOSqLOKytagJymFP5XqDMQlep73R3mnT4s4xvQu-TO6Airhtjd8AzzSVnqSXVb04MERB-l3PN02EePTzS0XvplzJ4TN69u-76_x0gGXaJl_z-gjJg1rCmZkZsyCv3y0evq8nql-1DSl6sard6a5v7m5uPQ-jZwqemkKrlxen5mXVutVb36v1jVAG8M3Z-TsnCIL5x3AXXdXWk8Ue7whBeae7sbu7CfNczjWwYNZCG_l9m8Mc4qk75eZM4ZK3yG_ACrn4BpWnvTDvuznsLmXlY0pZj5UfyDbPBh8d_NeL8M-ZLR25y7plP9r5Nu--oNEkIUAKw1DZNmifEL-cPveBm_1nzsbmzu7e-s769k6ns7O519nZ2iX9oAktcfrpyDid0rDXdjlzhFCMgBIDwTccAbeElVtfTNM_SNVWd7u7ubMHjd5Y397a3d3oblZEncQ5l0cKi-SKWpq2pO-SWyBDe2wwjrkfxMJIEpS_SGqUwNjUXcmFthqJhKjbEdXbzctLZRyrqMyjZh3f_2LeFYi8z57EYrGpTj4PIJufsa89bKPxInXFi7jfpzaHanL5hle9IaMXqjuYIgWC4lubjJNcp7eJlcurd2tF0weUmeTZ-o2lvdg1f085snZvz6TrzQHo5wPEm8-GCJoe0Y6fdQgmYWkqB3vsd84XfnfDyAL1GAkKRmDV978_3b-9p_yz8e7u3vXmTD9YlWkVT7jjtOgMNtWwQTi1L4hoY5abghHASCbwveYN0ax4-0qb3xbR5g0zKvRIkalQIU4ZUz2gheA3IFOF6YhfWtQBNRlBcoNM9NP4RnGnIU0aBfz2KVUKbNKent3iVhIKs6nZRCtl0l9hQD_RQa8qRNz7pfQfLDmW-j5glO9yDpY6vURGyQV6RNkBwApGM3yK_otYCnQn9hUM20rGpnusxhQXghEg3VJEETyBoZvyrTbQrSVF83cZ0Z3kYaiKfF1qi2M2YWfeMRtC0UQGXLDmNs6ppy0pXrJaEcZWJaJlNdTFl6gfrJv2VRg6oexrK7Zp2x-ndKdNukT99FpcBJTSoMYh-umqxDayUr6iUTRjhLFR8XpLba3XoVG9g2dDbHqZ9qhFOZ07YwmekPdeE4fU8v1O9rkaaVlgf_eE0jHsDYX5oaDGE_NzMBQs0jn24zRau6ftYEmQb1-PW85r2uRj3SjR1nmt21G8pvT3X6g9crE-WO-OtK8KkCRSkbUmRqabkl58hudHGAMZ6-f2XRr6dRxqMy9e8XlSqk7Ri-krHF6o12pVR3rL3ko4tzhIM9p0UvSVJ0m_j22TADfYrDhv88s7LdLMRjWvehMVZiRO2VbYVziABW2kZt4QKljI1iUMqODA4QYxx8r5bC9NZNCVeaPGbRwP-AXYgVJhYatMbZjeHfd9u7OWGTBIlXnjk2RvrIwum4Ty1BTO_vaDbvb-337Q7f_jD7q16XcO-WcP-YcbzS85_i8)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 122 bytes

```r
u = unlist(strsplit(readLines('http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html'),'href="'))
regmatches(u,regexpr('(https?://[^"]+)',u))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7XzZchvJdu2z8RVpnLBIRqMKBDjziFSQ1ES1ODRJUS3f8FUkqhJAiTWpsoogZDvC4e/wk5/9F/4T/8i5a@/MGjBQlDqO/XJ94rSIIYedO/ew9lDI/vKXQhyIIg4Dna/qPNNpGOSrmZL@@yBWenVlnOfpfrc7mUxcfJ0U@KdIXS@Juie//OKO8yhcWeusjDM1PGivrK21MjWKZO6NMbfo4I16SLPVlVVaRr/AQv/n/7b/4Ze1lU6xtvaXv7Tb7ee0xGHr@Rhb4k8e5KE6vK522hfY5nnXfNx6rvMp/fWDe9eXU/GPrb9Jpe8H8Wh/3d1S0Z9bfzNIMl9lDg/c10kY@PWHk8DPx/v99IE@kt7dCLvEvuMlYZLtZ6PBan@r3@n3e53e9sYaxtjxW@s8YxgmMt/PgtE4b/1z63nX0vK8a0kfJP5UDEa82kH79evXx6@P2/jcU3GuMryQwrApiH31wKxrH46TSD3vysPWP9Xfl4xtH/LZZ78c6M9D@dV@//rot@Xf9@2AXHnjOPBkKJYMTWWqMm1HpsUgxMA8SGI9P/Djm37PDqOXwkycH7WZj@2gG9B9@X7@@zwpso1yBF4vni3NklEmowj3acdd1p/MD/ZjZQe9fPZqgQtBYr/Eq/kvA7qP@0BNyrPXH8wPvQ98lZTDzJv5IV@LJFflEPNmfohM04q3dmDzo/nhrCtQlVGQj4sB61qgEy9NuydpepJk6k0BSkLSz@4gTAbdSGocYPFbN/Lbh6Pq7fw@WDgNwloEqvc88Hm3ElzMvhOZCsE6L4nbIp@mCq8jOVLdNB617XpDeU/fOxv9h42@S180pX/cO3w@OLwZK9Jo0bhY8V7GowJrQZN6h@J5dzCzeSpkGIziA1a8w9ZZ4gfDQPniwsuTgcpEb68j@uv9HkYetmjpQAspRipWmQydtMjSRCvREC0R2v3EBAzG2EEgtciTicx8LfQUvIx0qzkhH8u89bwImRWH2GCpOv4JhA1VpmJP4X7FQOU4gDgxzKR5ukjTJMsfme2FUuv2oS9zKeQAxk96JB0/Oj1J0vZhMviivNxJsoC45zdP/aPrMOMCD3JjXsyv4eJumBPg9kXWEUEsknyMg05gY/V@fQMVl4dJJnw1DGJipYx9UWi@BbpPZ6LoT/PA2m2d5mKMK9G4dty1J@Nc4GsVj/Kxpg0l/JMWE@yqMDDzcXNKRHAYYDo@iP0QZ1e4DCx4r8Ip75rzcBrZXJdkPlQPQT6FBOBdaqTCbd2MA9rLCwtfaRHJeAoN0DBbnsKwmMiFTvmlvPAWUeGNcVz4FFZsWF36NIiHmSRn5uVFRpN95Qrm300mYx0aI7DPAib4ip7LVm0JyPmqwTjRObg2UupOs0XQXkCS1m1cj1Oy3BlAAo8V/FChdSBje29YedHIEDmZVlNlVq0crwN@OZ6zbPn24XUq40CPH1sXyyq/yO3pkoyX/iK/Te/q9bLkHmt8kY7XbR9ePU0nzIlWOa9UfHO8NCw0/dc@/PBtoO6@e8IwSGWWD0PcPc/Ps3p@6Y@K7K4@EAs4LBbMz6lYXeq3j7/ILFaiBio0da0lI5IziDvJGJSC7h/aOApIGAIStQiaCYVIhmQG3danpBAQRAH1YBGt1KbD74z//lpABEmNjOYEeaeU6MaAFg2otjDjiBAvCwaKpFBE04bKJ8ldeXh@TfR3Ws0hs/CgcvmdFpYaQ8YzBXOJc/B0MZgaO6BL2sAXvOARZnI9hLSrVMahzKB5idEwqCABUXyfTckw08rglgIPyaIEg0xmU7d1FOsJLZjbaXR8ViLYkaTI2cEQUwfKaCMOX5tvnFF8F011HhvWr1EZLh7gj096U95ABbEWpo/CRGuivJ5ffsQb0jpmlgYcFD8KVNgviVNYvHslRrB0sVUBcrLzCkkA3qAIN8lG0DnzRsC26CA3GBRXNT@tMYV52648@OvKzi1qzU2SBp41adai2WX/FCooTkDY4L19ZeRFSW9Mb0rIOzurBjHtw7fJhG5@koFsMUoS2F2yYfEjU3WO9eEkDOWn1xdMffnpkglNaNY@PGq864gKInWEyj13yWwVQdt8he1e2Veli1gy2Eh0QKd6X758dOU3H06N7OCFqGYa7iVJuGx9Y4fMLPOah8O1QaumSyaULg4EvTEIqvJ6y9Y3iLh9eFsj4zleZnnghbTcSRKGyjh4MgnlF0tpgNMgBl6ZFxaNlqDDSFhTsmIZAY4uv@frxj1X4KQcGnzD7cAq0eBVnkX6FZfOu5yrxUU2grP6xl@skf1DkBdCHzL@xODIapqupiWNabhXTfAAwKV1dH59ajY8ighjwVSdL256CpAR5EWu1jqt43LCMaQejmr5MLYjL0/PzdA3KoN1fIquNTbGtZNqKoeYgNpA68L4j97e3i72EAADsMeZuodxiOmL/vr6hjH7@FJ@IUeVwjTAh2G1Xq8zt861SnNSkwwTez2Y8yEBZTJmZsKm@bNjlsTL/jrMVEZuNYSVg98R0vMANxmbJ9g0VhMhowFYA68jNpwpTIvQ3hgoJFTmgB6wF@NIc7RORSqfA4wwVHIYrMeGUIQV6/uGALfhQGi5P2orV4zEk8lljw5wmOCaWIx4UusJw61zSPi8FYMVIKiL8xuNclsf@AJ8nG5UAPiE08fQ0ezSXUJ9tSaNk5DWFn4mh/mMzXRb54h0jQfKGSoDJAOjCk9lOZAxQHecANcLSCZkS4Y11BmpnKFLMgQGxzeEffAvLpauQQyzxIAoOiQ4dH56fcOs8qQem1UIN1DK6o6wPQQgVso3pOBTpbWY2kGyMtg1MsJrRhPGCAJ1Qg7gV2UZn2AiPJG6Vw1nushvrBsFCPCUWKWUyFq1CBnkpXeI0CIGa31m9Zfc6wHC9/vdyajfQ@BW8qLyxWxTFqSDGQNRLmU5JzbyhzVpCHwQ3rmt9hkhJ7AlZn7gRAjSJMeF4NldDDdar4no7U5gl9xKbLmc216O7584UddPPN01uK8LLd/qxpube3039Yftw7OpIAxDlE/o0ljZhQZiDGGO@fgsBa2jNAtCMhJbTXE7FT70CLIVTuRUszhNzOd0Oos@6f1KBGRIiiZHI3gxDdvRODEEAjEIi0SFxo2tgSinGaL3qfBCyh2AW7xg2xiKdofR7WhsBQTHIaC6LDNFsvOy9ruv7pOw4Ms0G/JFlxBdM1WKdLVxmaDRI4nm8JKwrr1u68195TFNFKH66hF6Gom572RfxCqsVAahe@UH7Bj4Hirq2HfCQHIkb9xmqaSVrFQYMJ3zzT8D3/bFGflJxvD4gm6DxpqIBnz0xjLwBCdf4VMjuBX6hm4VfFWhgmvz4Hm0HKrcRP4QQlYjfF7G9WDofRL4ckDu4bkh@jExn0t7l3jIIbJDI9FHJsShyxnPHK@QGWkcqdw0NfFClUUgCstDu61HzPNfJwd4JBA7E3X1RbBJJSqJe3QNHXsPHTIgAWUX8pI64uwfoQwgkgc9esLlHKZEcRlrHQlKFVt9EataeQl4qBoiug9bDtuR5Sz1YrW/uY7bGCm9RsoDhGrNOnQ9K82OsTg2/TfEZ3dqikjUC0J2ocYHWb9/mrO4BBHBjhzClMCRwOIk7MxsPqMjBhDAiHNZHI5JQkvrWjR2fFw9fjLiaMRVrSMOmEUTjSzJNnPcqDiDxHyczz7jlEBYoUfRpy5GozKcJhmh@orNyz1@g6F6oISYyc/cBzFlb7uVy52hpabY4K8g9unupzNEzUY15qZUZT1TSYlAWKBbs5N4X25vmUKo1GT2cvV4vrukw5iaRu7bLvNWxtp554rjRI2jFb304OMBfemSo@6OKJVVIbuTEr2KkcwGZGC9KgRiw2/wspcUJE8gg2ZSbDRESIB7sqMTSpxIDeHDwcl2kadurS6jZRoCKLraLZw8uZsmrvTcLylR5Y88V5szf4gDBlo5e5IbGmdzHksWHKmE/IxHt0oJ4fodZ7tKgARpgdQw9Qy67mUQkmU1bIDgA/9mQj1IupD9pTulYRGNZRianS7tO757zo0sm0KpdpY31nZKhPqFl/PlYgn6NgaimklOLKre9yPwGU2Dd3nIVcwwworOAmGeUyUWCRSZjGE6Tl8kKd37Acj9HOWZUs9OEQIF/sHWTvuwxHMkKxU9NQp6Yg@O7ulVQ3JrHasvY2Z1hn9wpsuFGpY4SsdFpo0@e6SYA12WAEuIWC9mE1/u4/YBphmLgcj24XH50hjvIzjENIFAJjABEJhWvWykCM@RMyVwCvsUGkMwj1HrxODS/XUOBrjSTwYm/ds@vL55Lwel76i1klOVSmUOhYRqQvae0ANcS8VA67orGjutkHC1HJV5LBYRdjmDpEFqGa4LI2RVRUIwN0QleoRPyMmQuZChpoqEjSqoBscZzyM6iCDsvUhNlWLIOf43BZxTqtOVGy9whxYy6zRYNAnugq4fQMjkFI4@7Nq1fuG1frFrwb2fvm9c/GvymhAWLG/KYLTW/iKmIbWdG9WdkJR1@ZBdEramnzBxhjnrgo6Uthqu12kAPREXJrUSNuTU4AGA7AcPwkQqB5uVaxuI1y6S0gkz9b8qyb7ceiWJ3c1oJN4aqH1hynEXZTnu3I4Sl1zthA8wlTJ7zsY9YneaapPpiC1DUzIDtRwKQSAXrzJLEigsIJzrjflN@/Dq4uKmsiTi5NXVOWdD9IzQVLFFBPTWWWLDfdiKMJEk1t8xpU8nG5vmtL@@vu1wgmVRQPwQvitiXvpJ0JUD3e2tu73e5lZ3Y2N3e6O/TvzNgvsyJhBelkx8q7AIEGLWR5iN0Of8DWWotv/z3//rX//jv/7l32hTlhyB/xligNV6Do1pEgOc58iQkhoOZygM1KcYjvdtVDgDc1JiFSlepiB1jc2r1Rvy2tvb2XPoi7kd@2VA8dawzeKTfVFNmDHzdGOMXaBJ1jURCt7/g8FoI@VxgkULSpaUhJwVWhWPwSCdDHOqwoIODZjNII7vrxTkrveZPBb/00RJJt6tTatJj61S5NeB3HlFhR87toxkvPNaDfWS0Dfwu6BsSV7EMlc2/VRiQLwN4GNhq@FROtBvmFhTUG1UxEJEUGV3BheY6Ja5IIOFZZBByACEEW9HeoZlgM6ZSU5wxZiue5M@HUsIP2yXTUdQGDMMVOhDNCjREUkuB@ukzFyZZA@GD0Pok7bDBopROXRV/Zm2gnGPZcDZqUeiiSfqBHdBrueVcdmVDsP8znjs1@9vfn3Cv4/yuyiycIRfPzH@a@5YyTBb/JbXlbNl4ycPk8AfqVyb4R8fPpq3T6C77xdjlnKg0YnggGVOxHUpVaol/PGQnFYZ8JuMGQA6HC1ci2TRMGVaLjYANC7ZeZ4z765fO0e3TlaEgAC8Ez4hrSdNxEtB4nevxlQyKTMjLJ1lnqheVDQKuLU7vLkyyzaTmVUKc0WLmys6SmOCWfBWQfE5kWwpnmfjjJuE@JPSfaFGDNxA4I25VYI80r44xUvKQAY5MeVkLFMyLv0tDgSncLEP@WzW6rvNYPviEurpBdBuI9mXfGe4l4r3T4gGMCtXfL@vC3MZ8qH8WhZO6T0Y174uSA5oNWsNOF1g249MenpA7UeEdqhywUzg9Dd3zRAFVdruu2Vp97FhP1iWXjIfM9Yf8HW9wPrD/HCZaQrFxAlldB6x/qnMpB4HQxsu/PKLA7KcEDYe5sAUQJ6MEL6QzfNdX0UJRXVucdf1tNet2TCDo6uYo2UBMl06Y5h7GRYMXAxgXjUtPJUpx3XMpSXmE@hlNLFWO8Pl9lF@1aVQ6O4JHbnLxe32If9xPQecICypqc80rShmHxkDdnK7UDPFz6ajkT3omvgZWnUP0dbfC2N/rKrelHNKEyvgJAjqip6Duw@5@G9Rxh9MAFLKb1n@b1m6r7f3Q@k@CooCVk2u6/W2XHH0V0npzYbbVbGcL9EuXF4O07E0pAcPnLGrwFxPRpS3gfSPVZh28zTsljBTd@vGYAPRZDTIyA@KRlbnFWFfZcDLS0WNTyTqTdDYzGPMBr/MURP86tkGmmR5TUt6XmE8MmnQ0cnJB1vW1rCRQSXUdSrsA9Ahbqqscn1Hop/qRPiuyW7SBhNEhNGcP7dk5fmAt8AtxqFl6c5UNdpPH8Btt04pC0k9DFRd7ZBomVopB/y3H3j8Be6EwiZsMJLfOBlfystCu1zsUsxturKIaI7AqYD3@eTv@sf4/@dTP0gibcx8wK9Z6p5g4w81YDR5@VZlA3FdUO/qip6Tj@XQL8knEFuweaanYwjsbkszcVkUYUWwLaCqzolYoCTLQhDXdiyrflX3MOTirYKdmuqVWYIWU2NFBtsNhbGJHlOny9kyJHd1/6kaFuFsC4qpC3I5ai5@bVJzhCmRBF@WKgN/WWbMjKia6zKveR/qa53PObF5ssRQwj8sotiGOY9f7GLrjb1FimqXKsQUJyzKBA89ovHi/mBXnn49PY7O303PmNR9Mp1BTIVOE/zP9ngdWdOby/BOUCiHs/z27KhOyx2dnIFhhU@5Fc9iPFjYt9Kjbuh0xlLhWo/iO0CHjqD2SzV1W6/VICsoPUYN3a5t93lUw5cd6Hry7sOl@vjr1duEy15MLtTbJIeJ4VzNVVTQ0fZ@EYixSszWIXHabIwvaoo7dVB8bbpvGxZWaAVfKDO3VTamU57B/UnyX119e3U@/G2rd3L3LD/Y1gaxHytZ2FrmZTIxdcY2fC7gO2hr1xSfpCnwEO8sLlLFTudXNQUqhwQ3226YstQKy09RmCRqnN19unvjHz0bDrww8A9OJ0dXG583BqNPt68/@9tftn/98vb4YjOO0pPC2Ule3u1@Glyf7MpP2Ts/fHN/dJ98Pgr7w0@fPu993DQnJBQXxAXRq5bmJRpycyJhVbU4PT0VZ9KHAxQn11DY8iLc1jsZWyHq7bk/K0CXH5x@nL8sXvfWm@frbQ23rq@iaJpNfblzeq9Hp8ffXr4/uf3dO7v6tv353dXNwNvZ3v69d/6b5725Up/7u1@j6eaIDC8kJc21ieaGBYf9VItdbLAXq3k9BFiFumTX/ocZsLkR6bOvt1snt0ftw3NqyCVfAOL@1hByQ7oPJSq3hvEqyCkKRrl6cXdruVrXubon0JJlsH4G5I4lzHro7C3JAXrmuz030r4x59fwIsBAe86bBNRQw9y96po@bKfuw3ZOyx5ZR@YOl6RjB6Tsvmje5l52/sE78ZJ@Go9PbuLNo7dfbwYX59Hwt/vNl78mt0e3vTv16dK/3bu9/3X07erh5vQ2/fszGEmuLdodjN1baAVnRX0jgc1UKF7ipq5UYL1MLgxFxJxd24ziWfngAnwRKl13dytNkUIgQ4Mnq4RjpSPUC@3b8MVmC@kN@zFEZKm4lVq6/xPcxcfRgcf25xnR6aj4ADPIA5a3TI9XTI0QzbQA7jal5Ifl9OX9h/frn/qDdOrBVPb6ezCWH207EVfswRjuCwI2mwSQOJNJM/uXxvHOGEfyUWdKlfVxFxY3A@ygVPt9Reb2T6uS@jza3nr/4ff0@LR92C7tQBv4Ow0N3qR0YZ8aKou8LGf8QToobS4fCuV@/WogCCwqFeHLv4Hf7e9t7Ng0sM2dv06opnKsxoGBt5zDoAiht@sYosTNq5cPxt9T5yal1scyaDq5x@kZaO1qb@wOIuWOiy4jlu7AiFTzQZNpqjjVVnXWUGeM44HUScJba7qf48KXKZWab6pnGmubWMITJhQgPpoajCVHBUDJAHp4HcR3FEYTHPXVoBhxiSBSubT2l1QsDJOJiQISaDStozjFRxTONO84ZfMONsXqQIS8c9XDxpnnItSkkywNtFkjJORYEzIQmeTvRNmetiKDV8gpe009Q6VlcEXrTE7/mAzKy/vBQ3Fx/NvOugGjN4kvS37FjFqc@inR3Br3k3FBXZCU9yE2jhr1gGsERioHWKvHUO/ntBGO2jlua2O7lG135gQ/rex/f7F@@funs9s31x/ahxcUDDbqI0ufxQGYtOWYRyoZrT7CkoIeRlkG5j07yVavOCarUbvuJqDBdpAiMDeivbGOkMNAYXr0ycuCNF9i7rZ@@g4fvPT6/VV6cfYODuji8Wf82B@RSwliIIcgrxO5r04uLi5XelsVGqQcDXQD3roIp9@n6gd9Bb92zBtns@8s@o6g6TuMqyCMzsxrOFX7DI@BsqUnNGF7psTs46w/zNrFQ7y6pyRc9@Tyslv7sa3uR9MSh6MlvnPi9ABQ@aNRFRz2Nq2hnooKb4Ozd8twNlHEBP1xisAiqBg/68WmkDOaLumVWrNl3QpSbJm6JvUQrJQPQ/XW18XXQob8iCOtsIxnjyrkIpWqQaVzeelYOje7670N50ze4co5w@rcSH2n7Zv2IX0jNL8BGfjGvlnCy81HeLn5mKP5PiubRP4MMzf/ADM3f1q3v7z8@lvhD/Lia/JsqLgmeMDjXHqIk8qbMUm7aPOR2qwQCLmtAS9GVGz5Q7yhvl/n/NXvN/Urc4/WRLQP6XP3XD3kK7gS@6lJNDDOchwRDEHPNGfvhrecJp3YhCcVMm0b5Qt45u1d6wpKMEF8x0F@mu6mzQG9G12L5RxL4aLhaR825qz0NmbPQnjoFeFsT1XF9o9kxF@ZhjXOGOPTXfNYCj0CY59qsTlB4v2R2Nt@/HzpI5XN@yBSCZ9tY2ujv72zsT0bX5j@Nxa8xq9DWM/kIM7q2XaBa1t@Fy@hnWGSckKC4MbpzLPH3@vD/SF@N16TrPS7j/KcYoNez@F61Bz/@7P8Z2aawhXzcf1pPh4tZqMJwtgjuDLPbf7v6ObZDePFMtRkjtoCjHwsi7hsLeqEcthTud4wIsHrdTe6O11a3DmlB8KXyR1QEfeu8WPguabSk/TyuiEHhijIfmh/00mIrV9cK3pA5UaODmjvv@uv8@4Ay3RMfs3rIyQPGglnZmbCgrz@sHj5vp6oQd07pOjpqm6vv765u7n1IowPFDw1hVavrs7NE6tNq7e@1@gboQzg24vL904QBPPbcCtd3duTJx6fCEF5r7@xu7sJ81zNNbBg1kIb@X1XwBxi153qcKZwyUfkx2CFXHyMytNeWAzcAnaXsvIJpawj5Qeyy7PBRwf/HcX458KWjtxlLbMf7Xybd1/QaJIQIIVRqGwvtE@IX05f@MDN/oGzsbmzu7e@s7690@vtbO71drZ2ST9oQkecfzoxTqcy7I1TzlwhFCOgxEDwDVfAfWHV0cXPU7XV3@5v7uxBozfWt7d2dzf6mzVRZ0nB5ZHSIrmikaat6LvmPsjQXhuMY@EHiTCSBOUvkxoVMDZ1V3KhnVYqIep2RP2I8/JSGccqKveoWcf3v5gHBmLvsyexWGKqky8CyOZnnGsPx2i9zFzxMhkMqM2hnlw95tVsyDgK1QNMkQJByb1Nxkmu09vEyvXN@7Wy6QPKTPJs/cbShuyGv6ccWfdoz6TrzQXoF0PEmwcjBE3P6MQHPYJJWJrKwR77ncuFH98wskA9RoKCEVj1/R9P92/vKf8i2t3du92c6QerM61ildtOy/ZgUw0bhlP7lIg2ZrktGAGMZQrfax4TzctHsLT5gRFtHjOjQo8UuQoV4pSI6gEdBL8BmSpMR/zSoQ6oyRiSG@RikCV3itsNadI44EdQqVJgk/a0d4dbSSjMpmYTrZRJf4UB/U4HPa8Qc@@X0n@25FjqB4BRvss5WOr0EjklF2iLqgOAFYxm@BT9l7EU6E7tcxi2lYxNd6QiigvBCJBuKaIInsDQXfVoG@jWkqL5h5zoToswVGW@LrPFMZuwMw@ajaBoIgcuWHNbl9TTlpZPWj0SxtYlomU11MUnqZ@smw5UGDqhHGgrtlnXjzL6pku6RE31WlwFlNKgxiH6/arUdrNSvqJVNmOEiVHxZl9to9ehVT@IZ0NseqL2pEM5nQdjCVbJe6@JY@r7fi8HXI20LLA/fkLpGPaGwvxaUGvV/CYMBYt0j4Mki9e@03awJMi3z8gt5zUdckW3KrR12eh2FG8o/f1Xao9crA82uyPt8wIkiVRkbYiR6aakp5/h@RHGQMYGhX2ghn4ih3rNy@d8VivVKXsxfYXLC/Vao@pIj9pbCecWB2lGm06KgfIk6fepbRLgBptH7tv8/E6HNLNVz6sfR4UZSTK2FfY5DmBBG6mZx4RKFrJ1CQMqOHC4Qcyxcj7bSxMbdGUeq3Fbp0N@CnaoVFjaKlMbpgfIfd@erGMGDDNlHvsk2YuU0WWTUJ6awtn//qrb//6q2//Hv@rWpR875N8@pF9vbLfb/w8)

Output looks like this:

```r
 [1] "https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md"                                                                                  
 [2] "http://webhostinggeeks.com/science/programming-language-be"                                                                                                    
 [3] "https://coderseye.com/stroustrup-the-c-programming-language"                                                                                                   
 [4] "http://edutranslator.com/jazyk-programmirovanija-c/"                                                                                                           
 [5] "https://pngset.com/uz-cplusplus"                                                                                                                               
 [6] "https://clipartflare.com/tr-cplusplus.html"                                                                                                                    
 [7] "http://www.isocpp.org/"                                                                                                                                        
 [8] "http://isocpp.org/about"                                                                                                                                       
 [9] "http://isocpp.org/about"                                                                                                                                       
[10] "http://www.isocpp.org/std"                                                                                                                                     
[11] "https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard"                                                                                                                           
[12] "http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21"                                                                                                                        
[13] "http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4492.pdf"                                                                                             
[14] "http://www.stroustrup.com/resource-model.pdf"                                                                                                                  
[15] "https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md"                                                                                  
[16] "https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines"                                                                                                                   
[17] "http://www.stroustrup.com/tour2.html"                                                                                                                          
[18] "http://www.lextrait.com/vincent/implementations.html"                                                                                                          
[19] "http://www.hboehm.info/gc/"                                                                                                                                    
[20] "http://www.yl.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/gc/dgc.shtml"                                                                                                                 
[21] "http://www.geodesic.com"                                                                                                                                       
[22] "http://www.plumhall.com"                                                                                                                                       
[23] "http://www.peren.com/pages/products.htm"                                                                                                                       
[24] "http://c-plusplus.org/index.php?option=com_mtree&Itemid=57"                                                                                                    
[25] "http://c-plusplus.org/"                                                                                                                                        
[26] "http://www.trumphurst.com/cpplibs1.html"                                                                                                                       
[27] "http://www.boost.org"                                                                                                                                          
[28] "http://stlab.adobe.com/"                                                                                                                                       
[29] "http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/gil/Generic+Image+Library"                                                                                            
[30] "https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs"                                                                                                                  
[31] "http://www.oonumerics.org/oon"                                                                                                                                 
[32] "http://root.cern.ch/root"                                                                                                                                      
[33] "https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3386320"                                                                                                                    
[34] "http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/"                                                                                                     
[35] "http://www.fltk.org"                                                                                                                                           
[36] "http://www.gtkmm.org/"                                                                                                                                         
[37] "http://www.qt-project.org"                                                                                                                                     
[38] "http://www.wxwidgets.org"                                                                                                                                      
[39] "https://isocpp.org/faq"                                                                                                                                        
[40] "http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/"                                                                                                                        
[41] "http://www.jamesd.demon.co.uk/csc/faq.html"                                                                                                                    
[42] "http://www.faqs.org/faqs/C-faq/learn"                                                                                                                          
[43] "http://www.stroustrup.com/Tour.html"                                                                                                                           
[44] "http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/languages/C++.html"                                                                                                        
[45] "http://www.accu.org"                                                                                                                                           
[46] "https://www.accu.org/"                                                                                                                                         
[47] "http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms"                                                                                                              
[48] "http://www.gotw.ca/"                                                                                                                                           
[49] "http://curbralan.com/"                                                                                                                                         
[50] "http://www.artima.com/cppsource"                                                                                                                               
[51] "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aIqIBmNJyM"                                                                                                                   
[52] "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwJUPeWKRHo"                                                                                                                   
[53] "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERzENfQ51Ck&t=6s"                                                                                                              
[54] "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooehrkYkGdA&fbclid=IwAR3_3bgYVF_d6j6KjHBO4nmpCu-7oDk8YbSC8aYrJdlGvAvo_Al2fYY_9W4"                                              
[55] "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PU-2ntDuF10&fbclid=IwAR15f5SRmmyryda7IvsgIBzDLCVXcMRz6_JRTbc766X1NQccGRe_28qmy4g"                                              
[56] "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43msMqV5CVA"                                                                                                                   
[57] "https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/C9-GoingNative/Bjarne-Stroustrup-Interview-at-CppCon-2018?fbclid=IwAR19rNUcCco2pnhCTn4AHqTbONmfQv4DKoVAV1keYPdV9VvKgzRxTIVpZMM"
[58] "https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/C9-GoingNative/Bjarne-Stroustrup-Interview-at-CppCon-2018?term=cppcon&lang-en=true"                                            
[59] "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvUL0Y2bpyc&t=129s"                                                                                                            
[60] "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_g65LUXpBI"                                                                                                                   
[61] "http://daxue.qq.com/content/content/id/2937"                                                                                                                   
[62] "http://bss.sch.bme.hu/video/bjarne-stroustrup-type-and-resource-safe-c"                                                                                        
[63] "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPvbxuOBQ70"                                                                                                                   
[64] "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZO0PXYMVGSU"                                                                                                                   
[65] "http://www.computerhistory.org/collections/oralhistories/video/30/"                                                                                            
[66] "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcpSLRpOMJM"                                                                                                                   
[67] "https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/C9-GoingNative/Going-Native-42-Bjarne-Stroustrup-interview-at-cppcon"                                                          
[68] "https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/CPP/CppCon-2015/Writing-Good-C-14"                                                                                            
[69] "https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/CPP/CppCon-2015"                                                                                                              
[70] "https://channel9.msdn.com/events/CPP/C-PP-Con-2014/013-Make-Simple-Tasks-Simple"                                                                               
[71] "http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/CPP/C-PP-Con-2014"                                                                                                             
[72] "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDqQudbtuqo&feature=youtu.be"                                                                                                  
[73] "http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Lang-NEXT/Lang-NEXT-2014/Keynote"                                                                                              
[74] "http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Opening-Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup"                                                                            
[75] "http://vimeo.com/35326736"                                                                                                                                     
[76] "http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style"                                                            
[77] "http://techchannel.att.com/"                                                                                                                                   
[78] "http://techchannel.att.com/play-video.cfm/2011/3/7/Tech-Icons-Bjarne-Stroustrup"                                                                               
[79] "http://techchannel.att.com/index.cfm?SearchTag=Tech%20Icons"                                                                                                   
[80] "http://cdsweb.cern.ch/record/1204845?ln=en"                                                                                                                    
[81] "http://portal.acm.org/toc.cfm?id=1238844"                                                                                                                      
[82] "http://csclub.uwaterloo.ca/media/C++0x%20-%20An%20Overview.html"                                                                                               
[83] "http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-3478907067117491758"                                                                                                  
[84] "http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=5262479012306588324"                                                                                                   
[85] "http://technetcast.ddj.com/tnc_catalog.html?item_id=94"                                                                                                        
[86] "http://www.youtube.com/user/A9Videos/videos?flow=grid&view=1"                                                                                                  
[87] "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69edOm889V4"                                                                                                                   
[88] "https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/"                                                                                                                        
[89] "http://www.computerhistory.org"                                                                                                                                
[90] "http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/"                                                                                                     
[91] "https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md"
```